# Understanding compact extensions and almost-periodic functions

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, additive-combinatorics

This question comes from my attempt to understand theorem $7.21$ in [E-W](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.154.2590&rep=rep1&type=pdf). This concerns the dichotomy between relatively weak-mixing extensions and compact extensions. I cannot understand the proof as I do not understand these concepts. I will sketch my understanding of the proof until the part I'm certain I don't understand.

All systems are taken to be ergodic, invertible, and Borel.

**Definition 1:** An extension $\psi:(X,\mathscr{B},\mu,T) \to (Y,\mathscr{A},\nu,S)$ is said to be **relatively weak-mixing** if the system $(X\times X,\mathscr{B}\otimes\mathscr{B},\bar{\mu},T\times T)$ is ergodic. Here $\bar{\mu}$ is the *relatively independent join* over $Y$(See [E-W](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.154.2590&rep=rep1&type=pdf) definition $6.15$).

**Definition 2:** Again, let $\psi:(X,\mathscr{B},\mu,T) \to (Y,\mathscr{A},\nu,S)$ be an extension. Let $\mu^{\psi^{-1}\mathscr{A}}_x$ be the conditional measures on $(X,\mathscr{B})$. A function $f\in L^2(X,\mathscr{B},\mu)$ is **almost-periodic $(AP)$** with respect to $Y$ if given $\varepsilon>0$, there exist $g_1,\dots,g_r\in L^2(X,\mathscr{B},\mu)$ such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\nu$-a.e $y$, $$\min_{i}\|U_T^nf-g_i\|_{L^2(\mu_y^{\mathscr{A}})}<\varepsilon.$$
Here $U_Tf:=f\circ T$ and $\mu_y^{\mathscr{A}}$ are the measures on $(X,\mathscr{B})$ obtained by completing the conditional measure diagram:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
X @>\mu^{\psi^{-1}\mathscr{A}}_.>> M\left(\bar{X}\right)\\
@V{\psi}VV  @| \\
Y @>\mu^{\mathscr{A}}_.>> M\left(\bar{X}\right)
\end{CD}

**Definition 3:** The extension $\psi:(X,\mathscr{B},\mu,T) \to (Y,\mathscr{A},\nu,S)$ is said to be a **compact extension** if the set of $AP$ (with respect to $Y$) functions in $L^2(X,\mathscr{B},\mu)$ is dense.

**Theorem 7.21:** If the extension $\psi:(X,\mathscr{B},\mu,T) \to (Y,\mathscr{A},\nu,S)$ is *not* relatively weak-mixing, there exists a non-trivial intermediate factor $X\to X^* \to Y$ with the property that $X^* \to Y$ is a compact extension.

**Sketch of proof:** (For details see [E-W](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.154.2590&rep=rep1&type=pdf) page $200$ onwards) By the hypothesis, there exists a non-constant $H \in \mathscr{L}^\infty(X\times X,\bar{\mu})$ invariant under $T\times T$ ($\mathscr{L}$ denotes the fact that $H$ is bounded and not just essentially-bounded). For $\phi \in L^2(X,\mathscr{B},\mu)$, define $$H*\phi(x) = \int H(x,x')\phi(x')d\mu^{\psi^{-1}\mathscr{A}}_x(x').$$

One can show this formula defines a bounded operator $L^2(X,\mathscr{B},\mu)\to L^2(X,\mathscr{B},\mu).$ And, a priori, this formula defines a compact operator $L^2(X,\mathscr{B},\mu^{\psi^{-1}\mathscr{A}}_x) \to L^2(X,\mathscr{B},\mu^{\psi^{-1}\mathscr{A}}_x)$.

Using this and the additional fact that $U_T(H*\phi)=H*(U_T\phi)$, one shows that $\lbrace H*\phi : \phi \in \mathscr{L}^{\infty}(X,\mathscr{B},\mu)\rbrace$ is an $AP$ (wrt. $Y$) family in $L^{\infty}(X,\mathscr{B},\mu)$. Moreover, one can show that this family contains functions which are not $\psi^{-1}\mathscr{A}$-measureable.

Then if we define $\mathscr{F}=\lbrace f\in L^{\infty}(X,\mathscr{B},\mu): f \text{ is } AP \text{ wrt. } Y\rbrace $ and $\mathscr{B}^*$ to be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra making the functions in $\mathscr{F}$ measurable, one can show that $\mathscr{F} \subset L^2(X,\mathscr{B}^*,\mu)$ is dense.

**Here's the part I don't understand:** It is then claimed that the $T$-invariant $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{B}^* (\subset \mathscr{B}$) gives rise to the intermediate, non-trivial, compact extension. I assume that this is done by completing the following system of extensions from $M\left(\bar{X}\right)$ to $Y$:
\begin{CD}
X @>\psi>> Y\\
@V\mu^{\mathscr{B}^*}_.VV   \\
 M\left(\bar{X}\right) 
\end{CD}

The $T$-invariance of $\mathscr{B}^*$ shows that $\mu^{\mathscr{B}^*}_.$ gives an extension. And I guess the density of $\mathscr{F}$ will be used to show $M\left( \bar{X}\right)$ is a compact extension of $Y$.

**Question:** To complete the above diagram, don't we need to show that $\psi^{-1}\mathscr{A}\subset \mathscr{B}^*$? Is this obvious? It is not explicitly addressed in the text.

Thanks for reading, all help is appreciated.

**Edit:** As John Griesmer points out, $\psi^{-1}\mathscr{A}\subset\mathscr{B}^*$ would follow if one could show every characteristic function $1_{\psi^{-1}A}$ on $X$ was AP with respect to Y. I don't quite see why such a statement should be true though.

Take the function $1_{A}\circ\psi$. I want to find functions $g_i\in L^2(X,\mathscr{B},\mu)$ and estimate 
$$\int|1_{A}(\psi(T^nx))-g_i(x)|^2d\mu_{x'}^{\psi^{-1}\mathscr{A}}(x) = \int|1_{A}(S^n(\psi x))-g_i(x)|^2d\mu_{x'}^{\psi^{-1}\mathscr{A}}(x)$$

as $x'$ varies in $X$. Now if the $g_i$'s happened to be functions on $Y$, I could rewrite the last integral as $$\int|1_{A}(S^ny)-g_i(y)|^2d\nu_{\psi x'}^{\mathscr{A}}(x) = E\left(|U_S^n1_A-g_i|^2:\mathscr{A},\nu\right)(\psi(x')) = |U^n_S1_A - g_i|^2(\psi(x'))$$
by the properties of the conditional expectation operator. So I guess, I'm left trying to play around with the equation 
$$\min_i|U_s^n1_A(y) - g_i(y)|^2 < \varepsilon, $$
and hope that it holds for almost every $y$ and for all $n$. Am I on the right track? what would be sensible choices for the $g_i$? Apologies if I'm missing something obvious; I only understand these things formally and have no intuition for what's actually going on.

Comment: You are correct: you need to show $\psi^{-1}\mathscr A \subset \mathscr B^*$ (modulo null sets).  Brief outline: if $A$ is a measurable subset of $Y$, then it should follow quickly from the definition that the characteristic function of $\psi^{-1}(A)$ is $AP$ wrt. $Y$ (I don't have their exact definition in front of me, so I won't try to fill in the details here).  Then the definition of $\mathscr F$ and $\mathscr B^*$ imply $A\in \mathscr B^*$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Please have a look at the edit I made.

Comment: Thanks! If you put down your first comment as an answer, I'll accept and upvote.

Comment: To fix the earlier comment: Re: your edit.  You can use $g_1 \equiv 0$, $g_2 \equiv 1$: for $\mu$-almost every $x$, the function $1_{\psi^{-1}A}$ is constant $\mu_{x'}$-almost everywhere (in fact it actually is constant on $\psi^{-1}(x')$).   In terms of the expression $\min_i|U_S^n1_A(y) - g_i(y)|^2,$ we're using $g_1 \equiv 0$, $g_2 \equiv 1$, and the minimum is identically $0$.

Comment: Regarding the intuition underlying this particular definition of "relatively compact extension": my understanding is that this definition encompasses isometric extensions (i.e. abstract skew-product extensions by compact groups) while referring only to Hilbert space concepts, and I don't think it was immediately obvious that this definition is the "correct" one, which is why it wasn't present (to my knowledge) in the early ergodic theory literature.  All of which is to say: this particular definition takes some effort to build intuition around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct: you need to show $\psi^{-1}\mathscr A \subset \mathscr B^*$ (modulo null sets). Brief outline: if $A$ is a measurable subset of $Y$, then it should follow quickly from the definition that the characteristic function of $\psi^{−1}(A)$ is $AP$ wrt $Y$ (I don't have their exact definition in front of me, so I won't try to fill in the details here). Then the definition of $\mathscr F$ and $\mathscr B^*$ imply $A\in \mathscr B^*$.